# Shopware 6, display number of products for each subcategory

Tags: shopware6

I have created a custom block that i use inside listing pages where i display all subcategorier for the current category.
I also would like to display the number of products for each subcategory but looking into treeItem.category.products the result is null even if i have some products for that category.

```
{% block sw_cms_block_display_categories %}
    <div class="subcategory-block-container">
        {% set currentCategoryName = page.header.navigation.active.id %}
        {% set currentCategoryId = page.header.navigation.active.id %}
        {% set currentCategoryChildren = page.header.navigation.getChildren(currentCategoryId).tree %}

        {% for treeItem in currentCategoryChildren %}
        {% set category = treeItem.category %}
        {{dump(category.products)}} 
        {% set name = category.translated.name %}
        <a href="{{ category_url(category) }}" class="custom-category-item"> {{name}} <a> (here is where i want to display the number of products for current category)

        {% endfor %}

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plugin you'll need to [create a subscriber](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/listening-to-events) and listen to events related to both category criteria processing and result loading. You then need to alter both the search criteria by adding an aggregation, as well as the search result where you set aggregated values to the category entities as an extension.

```php
class CategorySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            'sales_channel.category.process.criteria' => 'onCategoryCriteriaProcessed',
            'sales_channel.category.search.result.loaded' => 'onCategorySearchResultLoaded',
        ];
    }

    public function onCategoryCriteriaProcessed(SalesChannelProcessCriteriaEvent $event): void
    {
        $criteria = $event->getCriteria();

        if ($criteria->getTitle() !== 'header::navigation') {
            return;
        }

        // setting the offset as a workaround to force `sales_channel.category.search.result.loaded` be dispatched
        $criteria->setOffset(0);
        $criteria->addAggregation(
            new TermsAggregation('product_count', 'category.id', null, null, new CountAggregation('product_count', 'category.products.id'))
        );
    }

    public function onCategorySearchResultLoaded(EntitySearchResultLoadedEvent $event): void
    {
        $result = $event->getResult();
        $criteria = $result->getCriteria();

        if ($criteria->getTitle() !== 'header::navigation') {
            return;
        }

        /** @var TermsResult $aggregation */
        foreach ($result->getAggregations() as $aggregation) {
            if ($aggregation->getName() === 'product_count') {
                foreach ($aggregation->getBuckets() as $bucket) {
                    /** @var CategoryEntity $category */
                    $category = $result->getEntities()->get($bucket->getKey());
                    if (!$category) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    // Ideally you should implement you own `Struct` extension
                    $text = new TextStruct();
                    $text->setContent((string) $bucket->getResult()->getCount());
                    $category->addExtension('product_count', $text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example it will count all products directly associated to a category. If you also want to count the products associated with child categories, you can change `category.products.id` to `category.nestedProducts.id` in the count aggregation.

Afterwards in the template, you should be able to output the count of products per category:

```
{% set productCount = category.extensions.product_count.content %}
```

Comment: hi @dneustadt, 
i've created a subsscriber as mentioned in shopware 6 guide, then used your code, i've injected {% set productCount = category.extensions.product_count.content %} inside the categories loop but dumping category.extension i cant see product_count.